# Meaning of the word "reverse" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is frim this [article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/finding-new-home/201902/why-do-people-kiss)

> So it makes sense that more frequent initiators of kissing (for whatever motives) are men; and that women engage “in romantic kissing in response to their partner’s overtures more often than the **reverse**”.

Could you please rephrase the last sntence for me please as I cannot get what is meant by *more often then reverse*?

Comment: Men start the kissing and women respond. The reverse in this context is: Women start the kissing and men respond. The first occurs more often than the second reversed one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'The reverse' means 'the opposite of what has just been stated'. The rephrasing you are asking for is 'and that women engage in romantic kissing in response to their partner’s overtures more often than men engage in romantic kissing in response to their partner’s overtures'. Such a sentence would be considered too long, repetitive and tedious to read by most native readers, and it is for that reason that "the reverse" is used. Consider this: **Jim buys Bob a drink in the bar more often than Bob buys Jim a drink in the bar**. To make this shorter and easier to read, we can write **Jim buys Bob a drink in the bar more often than the reverse**.

Answer (score 0):

Examine word "reverse" in the dictionary.

reverse as a verb:  means to move backward

as an adjective:  going in or turning around to go in a direction completely opposite the one you were just traveling in.

```
    as a noun: the opposite or contrary to that previously stated.
```

In this sentence, reverse is being used as a noun.

So, take the first part of the sentence before the semi-colon.

- The initiating kissing (for whatever the reason), is the man.

after the semicolon:

- Women respond to their man when he is initiating romance with kissing.

  [Add reverse to this statement.]  Reverse the roles of men and women in the statement]

Ans: Men don't respond with kissing if a woman initiates romance. [It's the reverse]

Now, just add "more often" - it just happens more often that women respond to sexual advances with kissing vs. when a woman initiates romance, men respond by kissing as a response to her advance less often.